# Nexus rest api beta returns two results for unique search

Tags: maven, nexus

I am using custom classifiers in my dependency management for tightly coupled items. My maven artifact contains two zip files:

- `package-1.0.0.zip` - the base
- `package-1.0.0-fulfil.zip` the secondary item

I am able to retrieve (and download) the first item using empty `maven.classifier` parameter (as per Nexus documentation) from Search API as follows:

```
https://nexus.my.org/service/rest/beta/search/assets
   ?repository=maven-snapshots
   &maven.groupId=com.some.group
   &maven.artifactId=smart-artifact
   &maven.baseVersion=1.0.0
   &maven.extension=zip
   &maven.classifier
```

...however similar search with `&maven.classifier=fulfil` returns both items (including one without classifier), making it impossible to download (Nexus returns 400 and complains that multiple items exist).

I'm on Nexus 3.9.

**Is this expected behaviour? Or bug? Nexus configuration issue?** There is a somewhat similar issue [recorded in Nexus' Jira](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-15202), however the reporter only wanted the base package and it was resolved by using `&maven.classifier` (without value).

Known workaround - download using full artifact URL instead of Search API.

Comment: This could be a bug.  Can you open an issue for it in the 'dev - nexus' project at https://issus.sonatype.org?

Comment: I believe this is as intended.  The "base" for both is 1.0.0.  1.0.0-a, 1.0.0-b, 1.0.0-c are then related to the base 1.0.0.  I don't have any proof so did a comment not an answer; I can convert to an answer if you wish.